# Change order of data with jQuery two-way data binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, data-binding

I'm trying use two way data binding to have the score changes on the fixtures move the league position of a team depending on the result. I've given it a try but not sure why it's not working. I have no idea what I'm doing. I've used tinysort to try and order them when the points attribute changes but don't know how to dynamically add to the points attribute and change the order of the league by changing a fixture result. Can anyone help?

```
getRemainingFixtures = function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/fixtures/later_fixtures',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(data){
    data = _.groupBy(data,'matchday');
    $.each(data, function(index, day){
     var matchdatediv = $('<div id="days">').css({
         'margin-left': '20px',
         'max-width': '80%',
         'display': 'block',
         'text-overflow': 'ellipsis',
         'white-space': 'nowrap',
         'float': 'left',
         'border': '#FF4742 5px solid'
       });

     // var h1 = $('<h1>').html(day[0].matchday);
     // matchdatediv.append(h1);
     $.each(day,function(index2, game){
      // var div = $('<div>');
      var p = $('<p class="match">').html('<button class="homeScoreDown" style="width: 50px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: normal;height: 30px; font-size: 20px;">-</button> ' +  game.homeTeam + ' <button class="homeScoreUp" style="width: 50px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: normal;height: 30px;font-size: 20px;">+</button> <input type="number" value="0" class="homeTeamScore" style="width: 30px;height: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px;font-size: 16px; text-align: center; line-height: 24px;" min="0"> V <input type="number" value="0" class="awayTeamScore" style="width: 30px;height: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px;font-size: 16px; text-align: center; line-height: 24px;" min="0"> <button class="awayScoreDown" style="width: 50px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: normal;height: 30px; font-size: 20px;">-</button> ' + game.awayTeam + ' <button class="awayScoreUp" style="width: 50px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: normal;height: 30px;font-size: 20px;">+</button>');

       // div.append(p);
       matchdatediv.append(p);
     });
     $('#fixtures').append(matchdatediv);

   });
});
}


function removeSpaces(value){
  return value.replace(/ /g, '');
}


function getLeague() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/leagues/later_league',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(leg){

    $.each(leg,function(index, value){
      $('.league').append('<div class="team" id="'+removeSpaces(value.teamName)+'">' + value.teamName + ' ' + value.playedGames + ' ' + value.points + '</div>').css({
       'padding-top': '100px',
       'text-align': 'right',
     });

    });

    tinysort('div.team',{attr:'points'});

  });
};



$(function(){

  $('#fixt').ready(getRemainingFixtures);

  $('#leag').ready(getLeague);




  $(document).on('click', '.homeScoreDown', function() {
    console.log("clicked")
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input.homeTeamScore").val();
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;

    if (oldValue > 0) {
       var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
     } else {
       newVal = 0;
     }

    $button.parent().find("input.homeTeamScore").val(newVal);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.homeScoreUp', function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input.homeTeamScore").val();
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;


    $button.parent().find("input.homeTeamScore").val(newVal);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.awayScoreDown', function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input.awayTeamScore").val();
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;

    if (oldValue > 0) {
       var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
     } else {
       newVal = 0;
     }

    $button.parent().find("input.awayTeamScore").val(newVal);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.awayScoreUp', function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input.awayTeamScore").val();
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;

    $button.parent().find("input.awayTeamScore").val(newVal);

  });

    // WANT TO MAKE THE TWO WAY BINDING HAPPEN HERE

// If home score input changes then run if loop to see who wins
  $('.homeTeamScore').on('change', function() {
    if ('.homeTeamScore.val' > '.awayTeamScore.val') {
      // finding winning team name and remoing spaces to...
      var home = $p.child().find(".homeTeam").removeSpaces;
      // ...find corresponding id in the league data
      home = $(home).eq($value.teamName.index().attr('id'))
      // targeting points attribute
      var homeWin = parseFloat('.team.points')
      //adding 3 points for a win
      return homeWin + 3
    } else if ('.homeTeamScore.val' < '.awayTeamScore.val') {
      var away = $p.child().find(".awayTeam").removeSpaces;
      away = $(away).eq($value.teamName.index().attr('id'))
      var awayWin = parseFloat('.team.points')
      return awayWin + 3
    }
  });

  $('.awayTeamScore').on('change', function() {
        if ('.homeTeamScore.val' > '.awayTeamScore.val') {
          var home = $p.child().find(".homeTeam").removeSpaces;
          home = $(home).eq($value.teamName.index().attr('id'))
          var homeWin = parseFloat('.team.points')
          return homeWin + 3
        } else if ('.homeTeamScore.val' < '.awayTeamScore.val') {
          var away = $p.child().find(".awayTeam").removeSpaces;
          away = $(away).eq($value.teamName.index().attr('id'))
          var awayWin = parseFloat('.team.points')
          return awayWin + 3
        }
      });

      // // listen for a click and update the scores in the fixture
      // if ( "input.homeTeamScore".val !== "input.awayTeamScore".val ) {
      //   console.log('not the same');

      //   // get both teamnames from the fixture from innerhtml or value etc
      //   var home = $p.child().find("game.homeTeam").removeSpaces;
      //   console.log(home);
      //   var away = $p.child().find("game.awayTeam").removeSpaces;
      //   console.log(away);

      //   // get the predicted result from that fixture
      //   var homeScore = "input;
      //   console.log(homeScore);
      //   var awayScore = "input.awayTeamScore".val;
      //   console.log(awayScore);

      //   // finding corresponding teams in league table
      //   home = $(home).eq($value.teamName.index().attr('id'))
      //   away = $(home).eq($value.teamName.index().attr('id'))

      //   // update the points for both teams 

      //   if ( homeScore > awayScore) {

      //     home.value.points + 3     

      //   } else if ( awayScore > homeScore) {

      //     away.value.points + 3

      //   }

      //   // reorder the league


      // }

    });
```

Comment: Have you overridden `parseFloat`? This will not work by default... `parseFloat('.team.points')`

Comment: This is too much code to sort through without a working example. Try narrowing the scope of your question by creating a small sample that re-creates the problem